# Problems with getting reverse shell

Tags: tunneling

I got a badUsb, my current solution is: it downloads netcat.exe and establishes a netcat connection between test-box and me with the help of localxpose tunneling (when I'm not in the same network).

The huge problem with this is that localxpose generates a random port every time i run it, or change networks, or lose connectivity... so I'd have to recompile the badUsb every time..
Is there a tunneling service that lets me reserve unique names instead of ports, like serveo.net allows for ssh? Because that way I have a static address to netcat to.

OR, do you suggest I use something other than netcat for the reverse shell? Is it  possible to download a small ssh.exe file and run ssh on the test-box, because then I'd use the oh so lovely serveo...
Thanks.

EDIT: I found out I can use serveo.net for more than just ssh... doh. Current solution: ssh -R REMOTE_PORT:localhost:LOCAL_PORT serveo.net

This way I can at least choose the remote port and use the same one every time, that is if someone else doesn't reserve it?

Comment: If you solved your own question, it's good practice to close it then.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: serveo.net can be used for tcp ports as well, not just ssh, and ssh can be used for tunnelling.. my bad.

I used ssh in par with serveo.net to reserve a static port on serveo.net which is a tunnel to my local server. Problem solved.